# PHP Session not getting started but using other session

Tags: php, session

I have my code in which I have used session_start() which is not working. I am using php.

Scenario is like below :

As in php we need to put session_start() in each file If we want to access session. So I have created a common file which is being included on each php page.In common file first line is session_start() & I have included this file in each other php file as a first line.

So when I run the code session is not getting started. It's redirecting to same page as session is not set & its not getting values inside session because it's not created.

What I did, for testing I created another test project. In that taken two files index.php & index1.php. Started session in index.php & used it in index1.php. So it's running properly. Because of which now my code is taking session file of test project.

So whenever I need to run my code, I am running test project first (so that it will get session created by it) & then running my code. Like this its working fine.

But alone it's not starting session & other session related checks are failing & redirecting to same page again & again.

Why this is happening ? whats the reason behind it ? Anyone have faced same issue like this ?

If yes, then your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: session_start() does not create session variable. have you created session variables?

Comment: Ya I know, but on first page submit I have started session & set some values in the session variables depends on what user clicked. But on next pages there is nothing in session,  it's blank I am getting when I print $_SESSION variable.

Comment: @Orion : I can show you some part of instead of sharing.

Comment: @Rohit sure, that's what i mean.

Comment: debugging: I would do: `var_dump($_COOKIE, $_SESSION, __FILE__.__LINE__);` immediately after `session_start();`. I can then check the the session id, in the cookie, is the one from the previous transaction. If same then the variables are not being set correctly. If different then the session is being recreated each time.

Comment: @RyanVincent Hi Ryan, I tried your way. When I normally run my code without running test project ,I am getting session array as `array(0) { }` then cookie array as `array(2) { ["_gat"]=> string(1) "1" ["_ga"]=> string(26) "GA1.1.530167015.1470709839" } ` , **but when I run test project & then run my code** then I am getting cookie array as `array(2) { ["_ga"]=> string(26) "GA1.1.530167015.1470709839" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "gjlph9fhcnruia1lu65bifqqs3" }` and session array as `array(2) { ["fname"]=> string(5) "Hello" ["lname"]=> string(7) "Welcome" }`

Comment: @RyanVincent Only the difference when I run test project first is I get `PHPSESSID` in `$_COOKIE` & `$_SESSION` now contains variables which I set in test project. Without running test project I am not getting `PHPSESSID` and also session array is blank

Comment: It means `PHPSESSID` not getting created after `session_start()`. What can I do ? Any suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check all your PHP files for stray spaces before or after opening or closing tag(s).
There must be no output before using session_start(). Session_start() must be at the top (or at least before any output is sent) or the session won't store data. (and output an error).

So, please also do error_reporting(E_ALL) && ini_set('display_errors', 1);

[edit]
You can also try to put ob_start() at the absolute top / first file, and the where your session is to be started, var_dump(ob_get_clean());exit;
If that's not NULL / '', you've found your problem.

Comment: session_start() is @ the top only in config.inc.php file which I included in every page.

Comment: Then, can you make sure that there is not a single file that outputs anything at all (even a space) before <?php session_start();?> is issued?

Comment: Other possible cause: is the hostname the same (www vs non-www for example?)

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you have put `session_start()` immediately after you launch the page, it should be just below the first `<?php` in the document. It should only appear once in EVERY page you are going to need a session cookie.

Also, ensure you have created the session variables and defined them `$_SESSION['id']` before calling them.

Comment: You can check my three files. I have shared some code from them. Check how I have included config.inc.php & session_start() is in that file.